# JSF 3.0 upgrade: CSS, JS and Images are not getting loaded properly after launching application

Tags: jsf, resources, jakarta-migration

I have recently migrated a web application to Jakarta EE 9 configuration, along with upgradation from Java 8 to 17. Also, along with other libraries upgrades (Spring Framework, Hibernate etc.), Tomcat has also been upgraded from version 8 to 10.1. However, once the server is brought up and tried to access the local application URL, following are some of the observations:

1. It is observed that the image (in .png format) is not displayed at all on the login page. When I tried to inspect in the Edge browser, source of the image file was observed in the following format: src=”/{application_context}/jakarta.faces.resource/images/logo.png.jsf?ln=serenity-layout”
   M not able to determine the root cause as to why the file in .png format is not accessible at the above-mentioned location by the application.
2. Furthermore, when I try to login for the first time (with the browser cache been cleared), login fails with HTTP ERROR 400. It is observed that the URL of the application changes with an appended jsessionid in the following format: {application_url)/login.jsf;jsessionid={alpha_numeric_value}
   However, when I open a new tab in the same browser window and try to login to same application URL again this time it’s successful.
3. Once I have logged into the application, it’s been observed that along with images, CSS and JS files are also not getting loaded properly.

CSS, images and JS files are stored in the following project structure: /src/main/webapp/resources/ serenity-layout (folders stored inside are css, fonts, images and js). In application WAR same folders and files are stored in the following project structure: {application.war}\resources\serenity-layout

I tried to modify web.xml (DD) to include mapping of jakarta.faces.resource. However, it didn’t help.

I checked Maven POM to make sure that no dependency is missed, however, the issue is still not resolved. There are no compilation errors in the project, or any exception observed during start of the application. Would be helpful if someone could help me here.

**Further findings update regarding response code**

I checked the response code returned by the resources and observed that it was 403 with the following error description: **logo.png.jsf:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403**. To resolve this, I have updated the applicationContext-security.xml file to allow access to resources with ‘.jsf, .gif and .js’ extension. For e.g for .jsf I have added a separate intercept-url tag and included pattern of "/**/*.jsf" and access as permitAll.

After this change I tried to access same login page again (browser cache deleted) and observed that images and css are still not getting loaded and got 400 response code this time with following error description:
**logo.png.jsf;jsessionid=E6DD8FCD9ABF746EF2364042CBF4E967:1

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()**

Furthermore, when I try to login by entering credentials, it gives HTTP ERROR 400 and the URL is appended with jsessionid like below:
**<application_url>;jsessionid=0230CB7CBBA342BA4B0BB2F82CDC323B**

After this I opened a new tab in the same browser window and tried to access same login page again and this time the whole page is getting loaded properly with all images and css effects. Furthermore, I tried to login by entering credentials and this time it was successful.

For now, M trying to analyze further as to why 400 response code is obtained when the browser cache is cleared whereas it works during second try. Please do let me know your opinion on these updated findings.

Comment: *"I tried to modify web.xml (DD) to include mapping of jakarta.faces.resource"* Don't. Revert this. As first step you need to tell which response code exactly these resources are returning. 400? 401? 403? 404? There's quite a difference. You also need to tell which security framework you're using. Also try searching through all project's source code for the string `javax.faces.resource` (most probably being used as URL pattern to allow static resources by the security framework), which shall obviously need to be migrated to `jakarta.faces.resource`.

Comment: Hi @BalusC Thanks for your reply. I have reverted the mapping of jakarta.faces.resource from web.xml. Also, javax.faces.resource was primarily present in JS and CSS files to access static resources (like images in .png format and css files). I had already updated them with jakarta.faces.resource during migration work. Regarding security framework we are using Spring framework. I have updated my findings related to response code in my original question as it won't be possible to accommodate in the comments section.

Comment: Hi, just to update on 400 response code, on further analyzing it was observed that whenever the browser history/cache was cleared, application URL was appended with JSESSIONID since the cookie information was lost and therefore gave 400 response code because of malformed URL. This URL rewriting happened because in Spring Security configuration file (applicationContext-security.xml) disable-url-rewriting attribute of http tag was set to false. On changing this configuration to true 400 response code is not being observed further.

Answer (score 0):

400 error typically occurs when the server cannot understand the request due to client error. It is important to analyze the server logs to understand the exact issue. However, here are a few steps you can try to debug this issue:

First, make sure that all required dependencies are added in your pom.xml file. You mentioned that you have checked this already, but it's always a good practice to recheck.
Next, ensure that your resource mappings in the web.xml file are correctly configured. This includes configuring the MIME types for different file extensions and defining the appropriate resource handler for these file types.
Double-check the paths to your images, CSS, and JS files in your HTML and server-side configuration files. Ensure that they are correctly pointing to the resources folder.
If possible, test the application on a different browser to see if the issue persists. It could be a browser-specific issue that is causing the problem.
Examine the server logs for any error messages or stack traces that might provide more information about the problem. These logs can usually be found in the application server logs directory.
It's also possible that there could be an issue with the Jakarta EE 9 server configuration or the Tomcat 10.1 server itself. If you are still experiencing issues after trying the steps above, consider checking the Jakarta EE 9 and Tomcat 10.1 server documentation for any known issues or incompatibilities with your application.
If you continue to have issues after trying these steps, please provide any relevant server logs or error messages so that we can help you further.